# How to make the navigation bar to stick to its original position when the browser window is resized?

Tags: html, css, browser, resize, sticky

I'm new to web-development and stack overflow. I'm first time building a website and facing some problem with the navigation bar, it is shifting its place when the browser window is resizing.I'm providing the source code below.I want the navbar to stick to the right irrespective of the browser size

```css
body
{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
 font-size: 14;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 line-height:1.5em;
 color:black;
}
#header
{
 height:150px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#ff0000;
}
.container
{
 width:90%;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:15px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
}
#image
{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:350px;
}
.head2
{
 width:50%;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:25px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 text-align:center;
 color:#6F0A21;
}
.sidebar
{
 width:250px;
 height:150px;
 padding:5px;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background-color:lightgray;
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}
.main_content
{
 margin-left:265px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 border:1px solid orange;
 height:300px;
}
#footer
{
 width:100%;
 height:150px;
 background-color:#ff0000;
 margin-top:10px;
 clear:both;
}
#header #logo
{
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin-left:5%;
}
#header #navbar
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin-right:5%;
 //min-width:643.891px;
}
#header #navbar li
{
 display:inline;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:0px;
}
#header form
{
 display:inline;
 margin-right:0px;
}
#navbar a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:20px;
 color:white;
}
#searchbox
{
 height:18px;
 margin-bottom:1.5px;
 width:200px;
}
#submit_button
{
 height:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
 <head>
 <title>My Web Page</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico"/>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="description" content="This website is developed by Soumik Banerjee"/>
 <meta name="keywords" content="Home, About, news, Contact"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="webpage.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html">
     <img id="logo" src=logo.png alt="logo"/>
    </a>
    <ul id="navbar">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contents</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li id="form">
      <form action="">
       <input id="searchbox" type="text" name="Serching" placeholder="Search"/>
       <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Go"/>
      </form>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img id="image" src="garden.jpg" alt="garden.jpg"/>
    <h2 class="head2">Welcome to My Website</h2>
    <div class="sidebar">
     
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
     
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
     
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
     
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
     
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

(I don't want to make the navbar fixed).Please help.

Comment: Please provide the least code, (minify your code), but at the same time, make it as complete as possible.

Comment: Please provide a working example also. If you run the code snippet in your question, in chrome, internet explorer and microsoft edge the navbar is staying to the right of the page as I resize horizontally so I'm not seeing the issue

Comment: Extremely sorry for the long code. as this is my first question in stackoverflow I might have done some mistakes as I'v not explored the site much yet.@YashJain

Comment: Yes the navbar is staying to the right but as I go on decreasing the browser window horizontally after a certain width the navbar first comes down from the header and appears on the image(garden.jpg) and if I decrease the window further only the searchbox and submit button stays on the screen.@Adam0410

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use w3-css for create a responsive web site. Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp).

It's pretty cool and easy. [This](http://ravana.eu.pn/) website is created by using w3-css.(my official site)

If you are  new to web-development i recommend w3-css.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually I also follow w3-css and I'm already familiar with the kind of navbar shown there and designed that before. That is why I thought to build a different navbar this time for my website and faced the problem.